# Graph api in ruby on rails for add to timeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

Whats the best available plugin for add to timeline implementations in rails. I have already implemented fetching friends, I have fb token etc. I used https://github.com/appoxy/mini_fb gem for that.

I want to implement a functionality ie add_to_timeline. Something like pintrest has. Take a look on screenshot.

Whats the best possible Gem/guide for this.

[image]

PS: I am not asking for the code, an example is good to have, even guidance for the gem or plugin is even enough :)

Comment: Can you tell us how you did it?

Comment: @Robin Hey, I am quite busy today, I will update a full fledged answer in next 48hours for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is facebook open graph. You'll have to define actions and objects. Read this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nov/fb_graph

```
app = FbGraph::Application.new(APP_ID)
me = FbGraph::User.me(ACCESS_TOKEN)

# Fetch activities
actions = me.og_actions app.og_action(:custom_action)

# Publish an activity
action = me.og_action!(
app.og_action(:custom_action),
:custom_object => 'http://samples.ogp.me/264755040233381')
```

https://github.com/nov/fb_graph/wiki/OpenGraph

And as kenny said, you'll have to create your own custom actions and objects on Facebook.